# Django - image does not gets display if object_list == empty

Tags: python, django, templates

i want to display an image if nothing could be found trough my searchg function.
I setup 2 serach functions. one for elasticsearch and the other one for a local search query view, anyways the one for elastic does not seems to work or at least it does not display the "not found" image if the object_list is empty, any idea?

elastic_search_function:

```
def globalsearch_elastic(request):
    qs = request.GET.get('qs')
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    if qs:
        qs = PostDocument.search().query("multi_match", query=qs, fields=["title", "content", "tag"])
        qs = qs.to_queryset()
    else:
        qs = ''
    paginator = Paginator(qs, 10)  # Show 10 results per page
    try:
        qs = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        qs = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        qs = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'myproject/search/search_results_elastic.html', {'object_list':qs})
```

template.html

```
<body>
    <h1 class="center">Search results <a class="fa fa-search"></a></h1>
    <hr class="hr-style">
    {%  if object_list.count == 0 %}
        <div class="search_not_found">
            <img src={% static "/gfx/sys/not_found.png" %}>
            <h2>Nothing found here ...</h2>
        </div>
    {% else %}
    {% for post in object_list %}
        <div class="post">
            <h3><u><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></u></h3>
            <p>{{ post.content|safe|slice:":800"|linebreaksbr}}
                {% if post.content|length > 300 %}
                    <a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">... more</a>
                {% endif %}</p>
            <div class="date">
                <a>Published by: <a href="{% url 'profile' pk=user.pk %}" >{{ post.author }}</a></a><br>
                <a>Published at: {{ post.published_date }}</a><br>
                <a>Category: <a href="{% url 'post_list_by_category' pk=post.category.pk %}">{{ post.category }}</a></a><br>
                <a>Tag(s): {{ post.tag }}</a><br>
                <a>Comment(s): {{ post.comment_set.count }}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Tell us the value of `object_list` and `object_list.count` (add something like this to the template: `<pre>object_list={{ object_list }}</pre><pre>count={{ object_list.count }}</pre>`).

Comment: May I suggest that you don't reuse the name `qs` for just anything in your view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about like this using [empty](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty):

```
{% for post in object_list %}

    <div class="post">
        <h3><u><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></u></h3>
        <p>{{ post.content|safe|slice:":800"|linebreaksbr}}
            {% if post.content|length > 300 %}
                <a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">... more</a>
            {% endif %}</p>
        <div class="date">
            <a>Published by: <a href="{% url 'profile' pk=user.pk %}" >{{ post.author }}</a></a><br>
            <a>Published at: {{ post.published_date }}</a><br>
            <a>Category: <a href="{% url 'post_list_by_category' pk=post.category.pk %}">{{ post.category }}</a></a><br>
            <a>Tag(s): {{ post.tag }}</a><br>
            <a>Comment(s): {{ post.comment_set.count }}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% empty %}
 <div class="search_not_found">
        <img src={% static "/gfx/sys/not_found.png" %}>
        <h2>Nothing found here ...</h2>
 </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thx dude :D
i was just some kind of confued because i already written myself a local search function that was able to work like in my first post but for some reasone it work diffrent here, anyways. big thanks!